# I embedded a matplotlib graph of a sphere into Tkinter, and can no longer orbit it!

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I embedded a matplotlib graph of a sphere into Tkinter. Now for some reason I've lost the ability to orbit the object, when dragging the mouse. Anyone have an idea of why this happened and how to fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')


from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  axes3d,Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FixedLocator, FormatStrFormatter

import Tkinter
import sys

class E(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent


        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.dest)
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3.5,3.5))
        ax = Axes3D(self.fig)



        u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
        v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

        x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
        y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
        z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))





        t = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4,color='lightgreen',linewidth=0)




        self.frame = Tkinter.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack(padx=15,pady=15)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.frame)

        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both')


        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( self.canvas, self )
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.toolbar.pack()

        self.btn = Tkinter.Button(self,text='button',command=self.alt)
        self.btn.pack(ipadx=250)

    def alt (self):
        print 9
    def dest(self):
        self.destroy()
        sys.exit()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = E(None)
    app.title('Embedding in TK')
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to setup your canvas before you plot, so move the block of code below to after this line `self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)`

```
        #Move this Code 
        ax = Axes3D(self.fig)
        u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
        v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
        x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
        y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
        z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
        t = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4,color='lightgreen',linewidth=0)
```